# I am getting a large black bar at the top and bottom of the screen in all simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, uiwebview, uiwindow

[image]this is code written in CDVViewController.m based on this only its showing content. [image: In in the image iphone screen scrollview moving under the green color view if i scroll up the view ..how to fix this as per iphone screen]Iam new to Cordova can anyone help me?

```
 -(void)createView
    {CGRect webViewBounds = self.view.bounds;

        webViewBounds.origin = self.view.bounds.origin;

        self.webView = [self newCordovaViewWithFrame:webViewBounds];
        self.webView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);

        [self.view addSubview:self.webView];
        [self.view sendSubviewToBack:self.webView];
    }
    -(UIWebView*)newCordovaViewWithFrame:(CGRect)bounds
    {
        return [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:bounds];
    }
```

Comment: add splash screen of required sizes.

Comment: @NiravKotecha hi, can you see my above screenshot that is the issue im facing now how to fix that ?? overlapping in 2 image

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you did not include a launch storyboard (or launch images for all expected sizes). Add one of those to your project and you should be fine.

Comment: still, a little bit black bar at the top how I slove that ..?

Comment: Can you please provide a screenshot or something?

Comment: I added screenshot, please check

Comment: Hello Andre Slotta, Can you see my screenshots im facing overlapping in the screen if I scroll up how to solve this issue??